# Count characters starting at zero?

Tags: for-loop, charactercount

I need to write a for-each loop that lists each character in
`mystery_string` with its index. Example below:

`mystery_string= "Olivia,"` output would be:

```
0 O
1 l
2 i
3 v
4 i
5 a
```

I cannot use the range function on this problem.
This is my code, but the number starts at 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
mystery_string = "CS1301"
count = 0 
for current_letter in mystery_string:
    count = count + 1
    print (count , current_letter)
```

I have been getting this as output:

```
1 C
2 S
3 1
4 3
5 0
6 1
```

but it needs to start at zero.

Comment: You're incrementing the `count` before the print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the count (`count += 1`) after you print in the for loop

Note: Also, please format your code in a code block surrounded with a tick(`) or multiline code with 3 tick (```)

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way is to use `enumerate()` in such a case. This way you'll get both the index and the content of your string.

```
mystery_string = "CS1301"
for count, current_letter in enumerate(mystery_string):
    print (count , current_letter)
```